# Check Network change in Progressive web app?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

How to get callback while changing network in Progressive web app?

Example : In Flipkart Lite, when ever we disconnect from internet, app color changes from blue to gray and when we connect from internet app color changes from gray to blue.
Please tell me, How to implement this functionality?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers.

Comment: I don't see why this is too broad. The question is really simple, maybe it can be reworded for clarification, but it isn't broad at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [window.navigator.online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) property and you can listen to the [online and offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events).